# Fast Rendering of Complex Environments Using a Spatial Hierarchy

Tags: algorithm, 3d, rendering, time-complexity, computational-geometry

I'm reading [*Fast Rendering of Complex Environments Using a Spatial Hierarchy*](http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~bradc/cv/pubs/conferences/gi96.pdf) by *Bradford
Chamberlain et al*. Let

- `S` be a set of `n` triangles in the space
- `T` be an octree for `S`

  - triangles "shared" by multiple cells of `T` are stored redundantly (by reference)
  - each triangle has a flag indicating whether it already has been drawn (in the current frame)
  - the subdivision in `T` stops, when a cell contains no more than a fixed amount of triangles

Then, the idea is the following:

- Let `C` be a leaf of `T` and `W` be the *color cube* for `C`, i.e.

  - Render the primitives associated to `C` using an orthographic projection through the ith face `f(i)` of `W` to an image `I(i)`
  - Compute a color for `f(i)` using `I(i)`, e.g. let `I(i)` be of size `4×4` pixels and average
  - Assign an opacity to `f(i)` indicating the amount of `f(i)` covered by geometry
- Now, if `C` is an inner node of `T`, a color cube for `C` is obtained using the children of `C`

Now, the algorithm `render(octree cell C`) is invoked for the root cell of `T` and does the following:

```
if no part of C is in the view frustum
    return;
if projected size of C is < ε
    draw the color cube associated to C
else if C is a leaf
    draw the geometry associated to C
else
    for each child D of C (in back to front order)
        render(D)
```

`ε > 0` is a fixed threshold.

> What's the time complexity of `render`?

In the referenced paper, the authors make the assumption that `T` has depth of `d = O(log n)`. Now, they are doing something what I don't understand. Let me quote:

> We refer to the part of the view frustum in which geometry must be
>   rendered as the near-field, and the part in which color-cube
>   approximations can be used as the far field. A far-field subfrustum
>   `i` is the part of the viewing frustum in which cells at depth `i` in
>   the octree have projected size less than ε (see Figure). There are `d`
>   such sub-frusta: one for each level of the octree.

[image: sub-frusta]

**Question**: Why can we divide the frustum in such a way? Take a look at the following figure

[image: frustum]

where the green cells are of size `≥ ε`, the blue cells are of size `< ε` and the red cells are outside the frustum. From that figure, it doesn't seem to be possible to find a distance `h` such that every cell less than `h` away from the eye is `≥ ε` (near field) and every cell at least `h` away from the eye is `< ε`.

> So, what are they doing? Why can we divide the frustum in such a way and what is `h`? (is `h` really supposed to be the distance from the eye?)